# Can someone help me with this simple calculator program in python? I am having problem in finding error

Tags: python, syntax-error

*Program got a Syntax error as follow:*

elif choice == "3":
^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
print("1 Addition\n2 Subtraction\n3 Multiplication\n4 Division ")
choice= input ("WHat is you choice? : ")
num1 = float (input("Please enter a number: "))
num2 = float( input("please enter another number: "))

if choice == "1":
    print(Num1,"+", Num2, "=", (Num1 + Num2))
    elif choice == "2":
    print(Num1,"-", Num2, "=", (Num1 - Num2))
    elif choice == "3":
    print(Num1,"x", Num2, "=", (Num1 * Num2))
    elif choice == "4":
        if Num2 == 0.0
            print("0 error LOL")
        else:
            print(Num1, "/", Num2, "=", (Num1 / Num2) )
else:
    print("your choice is bad...")
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. `elif` and `else` have to be at the same indentation level as the corresponding `if`. Undent all the `elif` lines.

Comment: You've another issue.
Variable naming is case sensitive then `Num1` is unknown, because `num1` has been initialized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Variable names are case sensitive ("num1" cannot be referenced as "Num1")

Indentation on elif should be inline with the original "if"

Missing colon on if statement on line 13.

Here is an altered version that worked for me:

```
print("1 Addition\n2 Subtraction\n3 Multiplication\n4 Division ")
choice= input ("WHat is you choice? : ")
num1 = float (input("Please enter a number: "))
num2 = float( input("please enter another number: "))

if choice == "1":
    print(num1,"+", num2, "=", (num1 + num2))
elif choice == "2":
    print(num1,"-", num2, "=", (num1 - num2))
elif choice == "3":
    print(num1,"x", num2, "=", (num1 * num2))
elif choice == "4":
        if num2 == 0.0:
            print("0 error LOL")
        else:
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", (num1 / num2) )
else:
    print("your choice is bad...")
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to unindent the elif statements like:

```
print("1 Addition\n2 Subtraction\n3 Multiplication\n4 Division ")
choice= input("What is you choice? : ")
num1 = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("please enter another number: "))

if choice == "1":
    print(f"{Num1}+{Num2}={Num1 + Num2}")
elif choice == "2":
    print(f"{Num1}-{Num2}={Num1 - Num2}")
elif choice == "3":
    print(f"{Num1}*{Num2}={Num1 * Num2}")
elif choice == "4":
    if Num2 == 0.0
        print("0 error LOL")
    else:
       print(f"{Num1}/{Num2}={Num1 / Num2}")
else:
    print("your choice is bad...")
```

I changed your code slightly and used f-strings to make it slightly neater (in my opinion)